# Assinar documentos com certificado digital usando php ou js

Tags: php, javascript, certificado-digital

Preciso desenvolver um código (JS ou PHP) em que após fazer o upload de um arquivo PDF ele seja automaticamente assinado por um certificado digital modelo A1 que já está alocado no servidor.

Comment: Lendo a pergunta não dá para entender o que você precisa saber. Por favor dê mais detalhes do problema e informe o que exatamente você não sabe fazer sozinho, ou a pergunta será considerada ampla demais para o site. O problema é como assinar digitalmente o arquivo após o upload?

Comment: preciso saber se existe um codigo (php ou js) em que ao fazer upload de um documento (.PDF) para o servidor do site
ele sera assinado automaticamente por um certificado digital

Comment: existe um codigo que assine digitalmente o pdf durante o upload?

Comment: Durante o upload o arquivo não está completo no servidor. Você precisa receber o arquivo todo primeiro, e depois assinar via PHP (ou outra ferramenta) no próprio servidor. Adianto que não sei como fazer, mas outros usuários podem saber, vamos aguardar.

Comment: é essa mesma a minha pergunta! pode ser que tenha alguma ferramenta responsável por assinar. Até o momento, sei que tem que ter um Certificado digital Modelo A1 dentro do servidor. Agradeço sua atenção

Comment: Não tenho uma resposta, mas vamos por partes: 1) [o formato do certificado A1 é o PKCS#12](https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/serasaexperian-eid/Manual_Usuario_eCNPJ.pdf); 2) [Essa pergunta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10903682/520779) mostra um meio de se assinar PDFs usando PHP, Zend e OpenSSL, talvez sirva pro seu caso; 3) Se seu servidor tiver acesso ao Java, há uma ferramenta - [PortableSigner](http://portablesigner.sourceforge.net/) - que facilita bastante o trabalho; mais detalhes [nesse post](https://paulbradley.org/digitally-sign-pdf-files/) (em inglês).

Comment: A biblioteca http://www.tcpdf.org/ pode ser usada para adicionar o certificado ao PDF. No site deles tem um exemplo completo http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_052.phps de criação e assinatura, mas como você precisa assinar um PDF já existente sugiro que olhe a classe http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF__IMPORT.html (métodos `setSignature` e `setSignatureAppearance`) para importar o documento e setar o certificado. Uma outra alternativa que _não é_ grátis é o http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-signer/details/#p-12. Nunca testei, mas parece mais simples que o TCPDF